# Отслеживание схожесть символов Java

Tags: java

Есть не тривиальная задачка отслеживать схожесть идентификаторов +- в %-ном соотношении. Больше надеюсь узнать нет ли какой то либы от гугла, прочее.
Для примера что то типа
z9e09d0a78cbbo762
надо сравнить с 
z9e09d0a78cbbo761
тут легко перебором посимвольно.
но вот уже сложнее.
z9e09d**0**a78**9**bb**0**787
с
Z9e09d**o**978**a**bb**o**710.
Тут O и 0 похожи. Так же схожесть a и 9. И т.д.
Можно конечно словарей наштамповать и расширять их но такое себе. 
Есть ли смысл вообще в эту сторону рыть и может есть готовые решения?

Comment: для компа 0 и O никогда схожи не будут, а остальная схожесть довольна относительна даже и для человека

Comment: Можно узнать где возникла данная задача?